# group by key value pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs

I'm trying to group a value (key, value) with apache spark (pyspark).
I manage to make the grouping by the key, but internally I want to group the values, as in the following example.

I need to group by a cout() the column GYEAR.

```
%pyspark

rdd1 = sc.textFile("/datos/apat63_99.txt")

rdd2 = rdd1.map(lambda line :  line.split(",") ).map(lambda l : (l[4],l[1],l[0]))

for line in rdd2.take(6):
    print(line)

######################

rdd3 = rdd2.map(lambda line:(line[0],(line[1:]) ))

rddx = rdd2.groupByKey()
rddx.take(5)
```

I expect the output to be:

IN:

```
(u'"COUNTRY"', u'"GYEAR"', u'"PATENT"')
(u'"BE"', u'1963', u'3070801')
(u'"BE"', u'1964', u'3070811')
(u'"US"', u'1963', u'3070802')
(u'"US"', u'1963', u'3070803')
(u'"US"', u'1963', u'3070804')
(u'"US"', u'1963', u'3070805')
(u'"US"', u'1964', u'3070807')
```

OUT:

```
(u'"BE"', [(u'1963', 1), (u'1964', 1)])
(u'"US"', [(u'1963', 4), (u'1964', 2)])
```

Comment: Can you copy your sample dataset over here? So, that I can work on that and also, how are you getting data after these codes.

Comment: I necessarily need to make them with RDDs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way with RDD methods:

```
from operator import add

# initialize the RDD
rdd = sc.parallelize([(u'"COUNTRY"', u'"GYEAR"', u'"PATENT"')
    , (u'"BE"', u'1963', u'3070801')
    , (u'"BE"', u'1964', u'3070811')
    , (u'"US"', u'1963', u'3070802')
    , (u'"US"', u'1963', u'3070803')
    , (u'"US"', u'1963', u'3070804')
    , (u'"US"', u'1963', u'3070805')
    , (u'"US"', u'1964', u'3070807')])
```

Do the following:

1. set the tuple of **`(COUNTRY, GYEAR)`** as key, **`1`** as value
2. count the keys with reduceByKey(add)
3. adjust the key to **`COUNTRY`**, value to **`[(GYEAR, cnt)]`** where **cnt** is calculated from the previous reduceByKey
4. run `reduceByKey(add)` to merge the list with the same key(`COUNTRY`).
5. use filter to remove the header

   ```
   rdd_new = rdd.map(lambda x: ((x[0],x[1]), 1) ) \
                .reduceByKey(add) \
                .map(lambda x: (x[0][0], [(x[0][1],x[1])])) \
                .reduceByKey(add) \
                .filter(lambda x: x[0] != '"COUNTRY"')
   ```

Check the result:

```
>>> rdd_new.take(2)
[(u'"US"', [(u'1964', 1), (u'1963', 4)]),
 (u'"BE"', [(u'1963', 1), (u'1964', 1)])]
```

Answer (score 2):

As @PIG points out, it's easier to work with DataFrames than RDDs.

Also, I would recommend using `create_map`, `collect_list` and your own UDF to `combine_maps`. This should allow you to keep working with structured data.

```
df2=df1.withColumn('result',F.create_map(df1.Gyear, df1.Patient))
df2.show()

+-------+-----+-------+-----------+
|country|Gyear|Patient|     result|
+-------+-----+-------+-----------+
|      S| 1963|      4|[1963 -> 4]|
|     BE| 1963|      1|[1963 -> 1]|
|      S| 1964|      1|[1964 -> 1]|
|     BE| 1964|      1|[1964 -> 1]|
+-------+-----+-------+-----------+

from typing import List, Dict
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def combine_map(x: Dict[str, int], y: Dict[str, int]) -> Dict[str, int]:
    return {k: x.get(k, 0) + y.get(k, 0) for k in set(x) | set(y)}


@udf(returnType=MapType(StringType(), IntegerType()))
def combine_maps(maps):
    return reduce(combine_map, maps, {})

df2.groupBy("country").agg(F.collect_list("result").alias("result")) \
   .withColumn("result", combine_maps("result")) \
   .show(truncate=False) 

+-------+----------------------+
|country|result                |
+-------+----------------------+
|S      |[1964 -> 1, 1963 -> 4]|
|BE     |[1964 -> 1, 1963 -> 1]|
+-------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you are looking for?.I am not able to convert result columns into Tuple, so just have concatenated as string.
Below solution might not be good in performance.

Run on spark 2.3 Ubuntu 18.04

```
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    import pyspark.sql.functions as F

    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()


    l = [
    ('BE', '1963', '3070801'),
    ('BE', '1964', '3070811'),
    ('S', '1963', '3070802'),
    ('S', '1963', '3070803'),
    ('S', '1963', '3070804'),
    ('S', '1963', '3070805'),
    ('S', '1964', '3070807')]

    colmns = ['country', 'Gyear', 'Patient']

    df=spark.createDataFrame(l, colmns)
    df.show()


+-------+-----+-------+
|country|Gyear|Patient|
+-------+-----+-------+
|     BE| 1963|3070801|
|     BE| 1964|3070811|
|      S| 1963|3070802|
|      S| 1963|3070803|
|      S| 1963|3070804|
|      S| 1963|3070805|
|      S| 1964|3070807|
+-------+-----+-------+

    df1=df.groupBy("country","Gyear").agg(F.count("Patient").alias("Patient"))
    df1.show()

+-------+-----+-------+
|country|Gyear|Patient|
+-------+-----+-------+
|      S| 1963|      4|
|     BE| 1963|      1|
|      S| 1964|      1|
|     BE| 1964|      1|
+-------+-----+-------+
    df2=df1.withColumn('result',F.concat(F.lit('('),df1.Gyear,F.lit(','),df1.Patient,F.lit(')'))).drop("Gyear","Patient")
    df2.show()

+-------+--------+
|country|  result|
+-------+--------+
|      S|(1963,4)|
|     BE|(1963,1)|
|      S|(1964,1)|
|     BE|(1964,1)|
+-------+--------+    

    df2.groupBy("country").agg(F.collect_list("result")).show()

+-------+--------------------+
|country|collect_list(result)|
+-------+--------------------+
|      S|[(1963,4), (1964,1)]|
|     BE|[(1963,1), (1964,1)]|
+-------+--------------------+
```

Comment: I necessarily need to make them with RDDs. =(